# Antd dark theme is overriding my own css. How to solve it?

Tags: css, reactjs, less, antd, craco

I installed antd to the CRA project. And I made some of my own classes and override default andt css.

Then I wanted andt table component but with dark theme.
So installed dark theme using webpack but failed. So I tried with craco and worked fine.
Using craco-less, successfully installed dark-theme but now it is overriding my own css.

After I checked the reason in inspect mode, my css is overriding default andt css and dark theme is overriding mine.

Did anyone experience in this kinda problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add ' "scripts" : { "less" : ____ } ' code in package.json. You have to load your css after loading andt css.

Comment: @JanithaRasanga can you please explain how to add "less" script?

Answer (score 0):

Following antd's [Customize-Theme](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Customize-Theme) guide you can use u craco config `craco.config.js` like the one in the example to override theme variables.

const CracoLessPlugin = require('craco-less');

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoLessPlugin,
      options: {
        lessLoaderOptions: {
          lessOptions: {
            modifyVars: { '@primary-color': '#1DA57A' },
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

In my experience you have to use `less` files to override the less from antd, so try to move your custom styles into less files.

Check this thread too, for a detailed description.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I said, this is causing the override of my custom css.